# Are there any sequel movies based on true story?

Tags: analysis

Mostly true stories sometimes also known as biographies end up in single parts, but I really doubt at the very corner some sequels on true stories exist.

So are there any sequel movies based on true stories?

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QfvLcozLwtE

Comment: Yes, take a look at Gangs of Waseypur.

Comment: Congratulations, this question is the winner of the [corresponding topic challenge](http://meta.movies.stackexchange.com/q/1941/49).

Comment: like 300? .....

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, there are many Biopics (Biographical Motion Pictures) that get sequels.

[The most recent is the N.W.A. biopic Straight out of Compton.](http://www.dailymail.co.uk/tvshowbiz/article-3206030/Straight-Outta-Compton-sequel-featuring-rise-Snoop-Dogg-late-Tupac-Shakur.html):

> N.W.A. biopic Straight Outta Compton topped the Box Office on week one and grossed a whopping $56.1 million.
>
> So it's thought that there will be equal interest in a follow up about the emergence of high profile West Coast rap artists including Snoop Dogg and the late Tupac Shakur.
>
> Following the success of the August 2015 release, TMZ reports that **a sequel is being lined up about D.P.G and featured artists Warren G and Nate Dogg, which will be called Dogg Pound 4 Life**

It will pick up right after **Straight out of Compton** ends.

A much earlier example is the 1946 movie **The Jolson Story** about singer Al Jolson. It earned a sequel called **Jolson sings again** in 1949, capturing the second part of Jolson career after a brief retirement.

Comment: Another example is the 2-part (not sure if that counts as a sequel) biopic Mesrine: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mesrine_(2008_film)

Comment: The Haunting in Connecticut and The Haunting in Connecticut2